# Execute script on shutdown/restart

Tags: windows

I've written a script that logs my time but I would like to automate the process when I reboot/logoff the PC.

Everything I've read requires you to have admin access.
Here is the problem.

Task Manager - disabled
registry editor - disabled
group and local policy - disabled
all administrative privileges are disabled

Comment: Can you access HKEY_CURRENT_USER part of the registry?

Comment: nope.  the pc is locked down tight.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/345298/running-a-batch-file-on-logoff) to see if it helps

Comment: That required changes to registry, I cannot view or edit registry.

Answer (score 0):

**First answer**

You can create a scheduled task using the "task scheduler" (settings), it should have the "Trigger" "When the computer starts". As the action, you enter your script.

In command prompt, you might use `schtasks` for checking if everything is ok.

**Edited after more insight on the issue**

Sorry, but task scheduling only seems to be permitted for users with administrator rights. In case you don't have this, I'm afraid that your request is impossible.

Comment: Unable to create task, don't have permissions

Comment: @Draco: I'm sorry, this does not work indeed. I've been thinking about autorun.bat, but that will have the same issues. I believe the only thing you can do is contact local IT department and ask for administrator rights, in order for you to schedule your task.